# Removing an array from a list of arrays

Tags: c#, list

I have an xml file and want to remove any row from it. For this reason, I assign each row of the xml file to a list:

```
List<string[]> lines = new List<string[]>();
List<string> clmns = new List<string>();//each row is written to clmns
...
lines.Add(clmns.ToArray());
```

As you may expect, `lines` list will be like

```
{ "1", "2", ... },
{ "4", "5", ... },
...
```

Assume that I want to delete the row (the array in lines) holding "5". How can I make it?

I thought I can delete the array by using `lines.RemoveAt(1)`. But, I couldn't find a way to find the index of array holding the search string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are awfully close. An array is just an object, so the following will work:

```
lines.Remove(lines.First(a => a.Contains("5")));
```

This gets the first array in the collection with a "5" and returns the array object to `Remove` which then removes it.

To remove all of them:

```
lines.RemoveAll(a => a.Contains("5"));
```

Comment: That's great! It works. Thank you! Should I study LINQ to learn such statements?

Comment: @Siha: FYI: `lines.First` will throw an exception if no line with a "5" is found. If this is not desired, use `lines.FirstOrDefault` instead and check its result before passing it to `lines.Remove`

Comment: A valuable comment. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the FirstOrDefault comment, that can bite you pretty hard :). As far as learning LINQ, yes and no. I used a LINQ extension method, and passed it a lambda expression. Learning about those will take you a different route than learning about LINQ itself (since it is basically a language unto itself, similar to SQL). In the end, learning both will be of great benefit though!

Comment: @Siha, as an aside (if you do start studying LINQ) the example I gave uses LINQ-To-Objects. The syntax is the same for all versions of LINQ, but they are separate things. For general use, the extensions are enough :)

Comment: Thank you. I haven't started yet.

Answer (score 3):

[List.FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method can help you here.

```
int index = lines.FindIndex(x=> x.Contains("5"));
if(index >= 0)
{
   lines.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is also a useful one!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop to the array list and remove it manually. Assuming you just want to delete the first "5".

```
foreach(var line in lines)
{
 if(line.Contains("5"))
 {
  lines.Remove(line);
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: This will throw an exception because you're modifying the foreach enumerable within the loop.

Comment: @itsme86 No it won't. It will if I iterate one more time.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it won't break if you iterate backwards. Besides that, I'm not sure what this gains you over using .First, .FirstOrDefault, or something like that.

Comment: Showing how to do it without using `LINQ`. Especially for people who are new to C# who hasn't tackled `LINQ`.